# Exporting HTML table to multipage PDF file using kendo exportPDF

Tags: html, kendo-ui

I am trying to export the dynamically formed div element as PDF using KendoPDF. However I managed to export the PDF for less data (For say, attached content below), but if the table rows go beyond 500 or 1000, I did not get the PDF downloaded. Instead, I am getting an error called `Download failed - Network error`

Note: I am already using a faster Internet connection. If this doesn't work here, it won't work in the end user's machine.

Please suggest/assist me to find a solution to this problem.

```
<div id="divUserreport2" style="display:none">
        <div class="load_more_items">
            <button class="button_normal" title="Export as PDF" id="btnexport1" name="btnexport1" onclick="ExportPDF()">Export as PDF</button>
        </div>
        <div id="reportExport1" class="table_cfn">
            <table cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td colspan="5"><img src="\..\Content\images\logo_login.png" height="100%" width="30%"></td></tr>
                    <tr style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;color: #67afe9;align:center;"><td colspan="3">User Report</td><td colspan="2">Date : 7/6/2017</td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Company Name</th><th>Name</th><th>E-Mail ID</th><th>System Role</th><th>Status</th></tr>                        
                    <tr><td></td>
                    <tr><td>Trial1</td><td>Al al</td><td>wepetturuh-1564@yopmail.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td>asas asas</td><td>ippemegece-8412@yopmail.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>77_Trial1</td><td>1 2</td><td>a@r.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>67_Trial1</td><td>1 1</td><td>ram@ram.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>56_Trial1</td><td>7 2</td><td>r@ra.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>hh_Trial1</td><td>a a</td><td>bob@bob.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>22_Trial1</td><td>1 1</td><td>22@g.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>jj_Trial1</td><td>ii ii</td><td>ii@i.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>kk_Trial1</td><td>j j</td><td>jack@rhyta.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>99_Trial1</td><td>post 20</td><td>post20daysss@rhyta.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>00_Trial1</td><td>post 5</td><td>post5daysss@rhyta.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>99_Trial2</td><td>today user</td><td>todayauthorss@rhyta.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>11_Trial1</td><td>1dayauthorss user</td><td>1dayauthorss@rhyta.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>00_Trial2</td><td>3dayauthorss user</td><td>3dayauthorss@rhyta.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>00_Trial3</td><td>5dayauthorss user</td><td>5dayauthorss@rhyta.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ii_Trial1</td><td>8dayauthorss user</td><td>8dayauthorss@rhyta.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>09_Trial1</td><td>12dayauthorss user</td><td>12dayauthorss@rhyta.com</td><td>Author</td><td>Active</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Below is the pdf export function call:

```
  setTimeout(function () {
                        kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#reportExport1"), {
                            paperSize: "A2",
                            multiPage: true,
                            margin: { left: "0cm", top: "1cm", right: "0cm", bottom: "1cm" }
                        })
                    //kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#exportimage"))
                    .then(function (group) {
                        // Render the result as a PDF file
                        return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group);
                    })
                    .done(function (data) {
                        // Save the PDF file
                        kendo.saveAs({
                            dataURI: data,                          
                            fileName: 'User Report.pdf',
                            proxyURL: "/Account/Export"
                        });
                        $(".preloader").hide();
                    });
                    }, 2000);
```

Comment: Can you replicate the issue using [Kendo Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/)/[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I am getting a "ReferenceError: ExportPDF is not defined", presumably because none of the Kendo external CDN references have been included. Additionally, you have a rogue `</script>` tag.

Comment: From official documentation: This page loads pako zlib library (pako_deflate.min.js) to enable compression in the PDF. This is highly recommended as it improves performance and rises the limit on the size of the content that can be exported. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/pdf-export

Comment: Works fine for me on this [Kendo Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iwASu/2).. No network errors..

Comment: @sandman: Yes, the content that i provided is less and it is working for me too. In real time scenario, the content will be 10 to 20 times larger. To be generic (approximately 1000 rows). I am getting network error in that scenario.

Comment: Oh, have you tried to include the [Pako Deflate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/pdf-export#setup) library as a reference to enable compression?

Comment: @Sandman & dev_in_progress: PDF got downloaded when I included  pako zlib library as a reference. Thanks for your time and suggestions.